# Convert key:list of strings to key:list of integers in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dictionary of key:list pairs. The lists are lists of strings, but they need to be integers. Here is an example of what I'm starting with:

```
dictionary = {
    "P4021a": ["1","2","3","4","5"],
    "P4019a": ["1","2","3","4","5"],
    "P4013a": ["1","2","3","4","5"]
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
dictionary = {
    "P4021a": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "P4019a": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "P4013a": [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dictionary.keys():
    new_dict[key] = dictionary[int(key)]
```

I get an error stating the int() cannot operate on a list. So I've also tried to add iteration through each list.

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dictionary.keys():
    new_dict[key] = dictionary[[int(value) for value in dictionary.values() for i in range(5)]]
```

I've also tried:

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dictionary.keys():
    new_dict[key] = dictionary[map(int,key)]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in dictionary:
    dictionary[i]=map(int,dictionary[i])
print dictionary
```

You can simply `map` to `int`.

In Python 3 as pointed out by [Bhargav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290069/convert-keylist-of-strings-to-keylist-of-integers-in-dictionary/32290095?noredirect=1#comment52457815_32290095), `map` returns a `map object` instead of a `list` hence you need to use

```
list(map(int,dictionary[i]))
```

Comment: Hey vks, do note that this approach is possible only in Python2 as in Py3 `map` returns a mapObject.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = [int(val) for val in dictionary[key]]
```

Comment: Do a bit of explanation about the code. Code dumps are usually frowned upon.